# Ojdbc10 and jdk12

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc

I am trying to connect to Oracle database Express Edition (XE) Release 18.4.0.0.0 with my application that uses jdk12.
I am using ojdbc10 as an external jar and getting the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class of driverClassName [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver] in either of HikariConfig class loader or Thread context classloader
```

My ojdbc10.jar is in classpath (it gets loaded in the application). And Oracle official website only states that ojdbc10 is certified with jdk10 and it doesn't say anything
about jdk12.

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be causing this?

Is there any way I can make ojdbc to work with jdk12 because I cannot downgrade jdk?

Comment: Why not simply update the driver?

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't the ojdbc10 the latest?

Comment: What are your settings of connection? We need more details.

Comment: Ah, never mind, I forgot that oracle names their JDBC drivers in such a weird way. Are you using the latest 19.7.0.0? According to mavencentral, it's only compatible with JDK 10/11.

Comment: Version 19.7 loads fine on Java 12. Check your classpath again.

Answer (score 0):

It is strange.

ojdbc10 is meant for Java JVM 10. That's all you can get from JDBC driver file name.
The rest of information(JDBC ver, DB ver) you get by "executing" the driver.

```
$ java -jar ojdbc6.jar
Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 JDBC 4.0 compiled with JDK6 on Thu_Jul_03_18:17:32_PDT_2014
#Default Connection Properties Resource
#Wed Jul 15 11:33:31 GMT 2020
```

In your case the problem has to be something else. JVM 12 should be able to load Java 10 jars.

Also IMHO Java 12 did not introduce any newer JDBC standard update(still on ver JDBC 4.3), so there will not be any ojdbc12.jar driver file - because JDBC version implementation is what really matters.